# How to achieve Blue Green deployment model in SQL Server databases?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, database-administration

In our Organization, we are using SQL Server Standard edition 2008 R2.  Our database sizes are around 200-500 GB.

To achieve zero downtime, we are planning to go with Blue Green deployment model.

Looking forward with following problems.

Schema changes in release deployments .
Patch upgradation
Data migrations
Do we have any  readymade solutions with sql server on this? Like when release deployments have to happen on secondary server?

Can we achieve this functionality with Always on in SQL server 2016 or SQL server 2008r2 Clustering?

Thanks in advance!  Please provide your suggestions

Regards,

Muthu

Comment: Not sure about blue green *..but always on can help you minimize downtme